# Dos Llaves Foraneas a una Mismo Campo?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la duda si es valido crear resto tnego esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE EQUIPO(
    id_equipo int not null,
    nombre varchar(45),
    encargado varchar (45),
    tel_encargado varchar(8),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_equipo)
);
```

y necesito crear esta otra tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTIDO(
    id_partido int,
    equipo_vis int,
    equipo_loc int,
    gol_visitante int,
    gol_local   int,
    id_cancha int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_partido),
    FOREIGN KEY (equipo_vis,equipo_loc) REFERENCES EQUIPO(id_equipo),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cancha) REFERENCES EQUIPO(id_cancha)
);
```

donde "equipo_vis" y "equipo_loc" hacen referencia a "id_equipo" de la tabla Equipo es valido esto o como podre  reestructurarlo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es válido porque ese SQL será interpretado como que estás definiendo una FK compuesta.

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTIDO(
    id_partido int,
    equipo_vis int,
    equipo_loc int,
    gol_visitante int,
    gol_local   int,
    id_cancha int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_partido),
    FOREIGN KEY (equipo_vis) REFERENCES EQUIPO(id_equipo),
    FOREIGN KEY (equipo_loc) REFERENCES EQUIPO(id_equipo),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cancha) REFERENCES CANCHA(id_cancha) --ver nota
);
```

Nota: Por cierto, la última FK tampoco sería válida porque la tabla EQUIPO no tiene un campo id_cancha, asumo que seguramente tendrás una tabla CANCHA

Comment: gracias  listo si funciona :)

Answer (score 3):

¿Y por qué no lo haces más explícito?

```
...
FOREIGN KEY (equipo_vis) REFERENCES EQUIPO(id_equipo),
FOREIGN KEY (equipo_loc) REFERENCES EQUIPO(id_equipo),
...
```

No tengo idea si como lo pones funciona (creo que no), pero por supuesto que puedes tener dos FK al mismo campo en otra tabla, sepáralos, nada te cuesta, funciona y queda muy legible